# I created a new subdomain outside the www folder and uploaded all php files to the subdomain.its not working?

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

I created a new subdomain outside the www folder and uploaded all php files to the subdomain. And i try to access the files using browser, we are getting black page only

Answer (score 0):

You need to log in to your domain settings, edit your DNS zone file and add a CNAME pointing to the folder which represents your subdomain.
The subdomain is not a simple folder. It just point to a folder inside the domain.
If you have a php server you can simply create a script to automatically assign the subdomains to the folders with matching names.
If you do not need dynamic creation of subdomains, the creating a CNAME would suffice.